# Handle when Folder.Files returns folders that do not exist

Tags: file, search, powerquery, programdata

I want Power Query to search the entire C: drive to find all files of a particular extension, such as *.pdf.  When I try to filter the file extension in the second step I'm getting this error:

```
DataSource.NotFound: File or Folder: We couldn't find the folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\Common AppData\Application Data'.
Details:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\Common AppData
```

The problem is, this folder doesn't exist.  Why is Power Query returning a folder path that is invalid?  The folders being returned by PowerQuery seem to be links to the folders in the `C:\ProgramData` folder.

The following M script (limited to the problem area) returns 999+ rows on the the first step.  If I run `dir /s /ah` from the same folder from the command prompt, it only returns 20 files.

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\Common AppData"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".pdf"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

My end goal is use Excel Power Query to find all files of a particular extension on the entire C: drive and return their filename, path, and size.   Note that `dir c:\*.pdf /b /s > list.txt` will not return file sizes.

I have Windows 10 64 bit and Office 365 32-bit installed.

Comment: That's pretty odd. I can't reproduce the problem, but it seems like there's some kind of indexing cache problem. Does Refresh Preview help at all?

Comment: Refresh Preview does not help.  I tested on another computer in the office (with fresh image installed) and it has the same issue.  It seems like a virtual folder (or something to that effect) is making the scanner think there are subfolders under `Common AppData`.  The folders being returned by PowerQuery seem to be links to the folders in the  `C:\ProgramData` folder.